# using android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE on rooted device

Tags: android, root

a problem introduced in android 2.3 to use ***android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE*** permission.
can i use this permission on a **rooted device**.
is there any other restriction to use this permission.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use it on a rooted android 2.3 and above

Comment: Not directly, as even with root apps themselves do not run as root.  However you *might* be able to use a root shell to install an application such that this permission could be granted to it.